# pygameでのアニメーションを移動させる方法

Tags: python, pygame

pygameで作ったアニメーションを矢印キーで左右上下に移動させたいのですが、やり方がわからないです。調べても出てこないのでわかる方いましたらご回答よろしくお願いします。一応ここまでできました。

```
class PlayerSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerSprite, self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_5.png'))

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(64,64))

    def update(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.index += 1
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Pygame - Platform ゲーム - \[13\] Animationを作ろう](https://qiita.com/sf_/items/8b40d6124a1a0b9d9708), [Noob here - pygame animation of my sprite updates when I move the mouse on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61780610/9014308), [Need help moving animations using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68110912/9014308), [How do i move a sprite that's animated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71550763/9014308), [How to animate the position of an object or sprite in Pygame and move it towards predefined positions or along a defined path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74163435/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

矢印キーで左右上下に移動させる時は[pygame.key.get_pressed](https://westplain.sakura.ne.jp/translate/pygame/Key.cgi#google_vignette)関数でキーの入力を検知して、方向キーが押された時に`PlayerSprite`を描画する座標を更新してください。
インスタンス変数として`x`,`y`を設定し、`surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))`のように[Surface.blit](https://westplain.sakura.ne.jp/translate/pygame/Surface.cgi#Surface.blit)のdest値(描画する座標)を管理する手法が一般的です。

下記サンプルコードは[How to move Sprite in Pygameの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16186396)を移植してコメントを翻訳したものです。
矢印キーで左右上下に移動させる具体的なロジックは`PlayerSprite`クラスの`handle_keys`関数と`draw`関数をご参照ください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import io
import base64

class PlayerSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerSprite, self).__init__()

        splites = [b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAxSURBVDhPY/hPIRg1gNYG2HucAWN8AKcByBrxGUI7A0AApBGfZhCgbSASA0YN+P8fAEZT7t44/gzvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC',
               b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABvSURBVDhPY/wPBAwUACYoTTag2ACcXmBc/BLKgoD/seJQFhoAGYAOGBa9gLIQAJsYCGAYgEshCGA1GEqDAboCe48zYIwM0NXgNABZIzIb3QCKY4G6XgABdAXIAJschgEggFUhDoMpTkhDPjMxMAAA5Kq2CLUDuuMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
               b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACuSURBVDhPY/wPBAxoYNat11AWKkhTE4WykADIAGQw8+YrKAsTYJODuwBmK1ZbkAC6OiYwCQXImhkXv0TBMIBhAcgF6E5jWPQCykIAdDGYHgZiNMMAshxWA9A123ucAWNkgG4IShggAwfPswwHthuDMYiNC+A0gFiA0wCYzTCX4AQUByIyBwawGYIuhmIACGAzBBkjA2S1FCdljNyIyyBc4lizMwjANMAAdpcxMAAAXozdU2YbTBUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=']
        self.images = [pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(splite))) for splite in splites]

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]

        self.x = 320
        self.y = 240

    def update(self):
        """ 10フレームごとにアニメーションする """ 
        if self.index >= len(self.images) * 10:
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index // 10]
        self.index += 1

    def handle_keys(self):
        """ キーボード操作受付 """ 
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1 # 1フレームで移動する距離。 例えば 5 に変更してみてください
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # 下キー
            self.y += dist # 下に移動する
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # 上キー
            self.y -= dist # 上に移動する
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # 右キー
            self.x += dist # 右に移動する
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # 左キー
            self.x -= dist # 左に移動する

    def draw(self, surface):
        """ サーフェスを描画 """ 
        # 現在の座標にblitで描画する
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        # アニメーション更新
        self.update()

def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    player = PlayerSprite() # プレイヤーのインスタンス作成

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        player.handle_keys() # キーに応じてプレイヤーを動かす

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        player.draw(screen)  # プレイヤー描画

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```